# Can we implement useSyncExternalStore with useState only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to search for its source code in react repo but in vain.

I want to learn how it works internally.

Does it also rely on useState?

Can we implement the same functionality with useState only?

Comment: I believe it is defined at [`/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L206`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L206), but not sure if that's the right one.